# No integrable function $g$ for which $\int_U g(x)\eta (x)dx = \eta(0)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

> Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open set and $0\in U$. Show that there is no integrable function $g$, defined in U, for which 
>   $$\int_U g(x)\eta(x)dx = \eta(0)$$
>   for all $\eta \in C_c^0(U)$.

I have no idea to solve the claim. Can anyone give me some hints? Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: look at $\eta_n(x)=\max\{1-|nx|,0\}$. What happens to either side of the desired equation as $n\to\infty$?

EDIT: Let $\eta_n$ be as above, where $n$ is large enough that $[-\frac1n,\frac1n]\subset U$. We have
$$\eta_n(0)=1$$
for all $n$. Now use the fact that $0\le\eta_n\le1$ and $\operatorname{supp}\eta_n=[-\frac1n,\frac1n]$ to show that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_Ug(x)\eta_n(x)dx\to0$$
for any integrable function $g$.

Comment: Many thanks. Can you give me more detail hints. I am very bad at calculus.

Comment: I have added more details.